# dd utility is not ready to receive kill signal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dd

I have a script which decompresses `.gz` file and copies it into block device. I use `dd` to get an information about the progress (I cannot use other utilities, like `pv` to do that). Here is a part of the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e
trap 'true' USR1

# ...

gunzip -c "${SVM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH}" | dd iflag=fullblock of="${TARGET_DEVICE_PATH}" bs=64M 2>"${DD_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH}" &
DD_PID=$!

echo "Decompression process has started: $$ -> ${DD_PID}" >> "${DECOMPRESSION_LOG_FILE_PATH}"

# Wait for dd process to become ready to receive 'kill -s USR1' signals
sleep 1

while (ps -p "${DD_PID}") >/dev/null 2>&1
do
    set +e
        kill -s USR1 $DD_PID 2>/dev/null

        LAST_LINE=`tail -n 1 "${DD_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH}"`
        case "${LAST_LINE}" in
            *byte*)
                BYTES_COPIED=`echo ${LAST_LINE} | cut -d ' ' -f1`
                PROGRESS=$(( $(( $BYTES_COPIED * 100 )) / $DECOMPRESSED_FILE_SIZE ))
                set_status "${PROGRESS}% processed"
            ;;
        esac

        # ...
    set -e

    sleep 1

done
```

As you can see there is a strage `sleep 1` before the `while` loop. I want to get rid of it, but I don't know how. If I delete this `sleep 1`, the `dd` process will be killed right after the first invocation of `kill -s USR1 $DD_PID`. Maybe that doesn't kill `dd`, but it somehow affects `gunzip` process — I don't know what is really happening.

So, is there a way to get rid of that `sleep 1`?

Comment: Have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38589/why-does-sigusr1-cause-process-to-be-terminated

Comment: @ccarton Thank you! So, it looks like `sleep 1` is actually a legal solution :) But I think that I'll leave this question as open in case someone comes up with a clever workaround :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

1. `DD_PID` is the pid of the shell that runs your pipeline, not of `dd`.
2. `SIGUSR1` will kill a process if it's not ready to receive the signal.

The shell may choose to execute `dd` in the same process as an optimization, but this is not something you can depend on (especially not when using `/bin/sh`.

You can also not depend on `dd` racing to set up a signal trap, so it's better to set it up yourself.

Since you're on Linux, consider just using the GNU dd flag `status=progress` for an automatic status bar.

Alternatively, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` and use:

```
trap '' USR1  # Ignore USR1 in inherited processes by default
dd iflag=fullblock of="${TARGET_DEVICE_PATH}" bs=64M 2>"${DD_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH}" \
     < <(gunzip -c "${SVM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH}") & 
dd_pid=$!     # Is now 'dd's pid and not a shell's.
```

Or to be `sh` compliant:

```
fifo="/tmp/foo"
mkfifo "$fifo"
gunzip -c "${SVM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH}" | {
  trap '' USR1
  dd iflag=fullblock of="${TARGET_DEVICE_PATH}" bs=64M 2>"${DD_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH}" &
  echo "$!" > "$fifo"
  wait
} &
read dd_pid < "$fifo"
rm "$fifo"
```

Or with `dash`, change the shebang to `#!/bin/dash` and change `trap 'true' USR1` to `trap '' USR1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 1. I have compared $DD_PID with the pid in `ps aux | grep dd` and they match. 2. The `dd` version that I have to use doesn't have the flag `status=progress` 3. Because of legacy issues, I cannot simply switch to `#!/bin/bash` in my script, but I have to use `#!/bin/sh`, which, for example happens to be `dash` in Debian =)

Comment: 4. By the way, for some reason I had to write `trap 'true' USR1` instead of `trap '' USR1` to make my script work. I also cannot explain that phenomenon ;)

Comment: 5. I can use neither `#!/bin/bash` nor `#!/bin/dash`. I have to use `#!/bin/sh` for legacy reasons. In some systems `#!/bin/sh` may, in fact, turn out to be `#!/bin/bash`, but I cannot rely on that.

Comment: Anyway, you have already done a lot for me and I cannot leave your helping comment without upvote. Thank you! =)

Comment: @Pixar Sure thing, you know your legacy system better.